# Perl program to replace tabs with spaces

Tags: perl, text, file, replace

I'd like to write a Perl one-liner that replaces all tabs '\t' in a batch of text files in the current directory with spaces, with no effect on the visible spacing.

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is in [FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-expand-tabs-in-a-string?):

```
1 while $string =~ s/\t+/' ' x (length($&) * 8 - length($`) % 8)/e;
```

Or you can just use the `Text::Tabs` module (part of the standard Perl distribution).

```
use Text::Tabs;
@expanded_lines = expand(@lines_with_tabs);
```

Answer (score 14):

You don't need a Perl one-liner for this, you could use [`expand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expand.html) instead:

> The *expand* utility shall write files or the standard input to the standard output with  characters replaced with one or more  characters needed to pad to the next tab stop.

The `expand` utility will even take care of managing tab stops for you and that seems to be part of your "with no effect on the visible spacing" requirement, a Perl one-liner probably would't (but I bet someone here could provide a one-liner that would).

Comment: that's OK **if** you have an *expand* utility which does this! I guess you are in the Unix world: in Windows *expand.exe* does something quite different.

Comment: The main problem with `expand` is that it doesn't have an inplace mode (so you have to use [`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) or similar), but `perl` does.  Pick whichever deficiency is least important to you, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

`perl -p -i -e 's/\t/  /g' file.txt` would be one way to do this

Comment: You'd probably want more space than one in the replace part of the regexp, though

Answer (score 6):

Use [Text::Tabs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Tabs.html). The following is adapted only very slightly from the documentation:

```
perl -MText::Tabs -n -i.orig -e 'print expand $_' *
```

Comment: Thank you! I adapted this to also normalize the file to unix line endings and to eliminate trailing whitespace:

`perl -MText::Tabs -ni -e 's/\s*$//;s/\s*\r/\n/g;print expand $_,"\n"'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -wp -i.backup -e 's/\t/    /g' *
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `s///` to achieve this. Perhaps you have a line of text stored in $line:

```
$line =~ s/\t/    /g;
```

This should replace each tab (`\t`) with four spaces. It just depends on how many spaces one tab is in your file.

Here's something that should do it pretty quickly for you; edit it how you will.

```
open(FH, 'tabz.txt');

my @new;

foreach my $line (<FH>) {
    $line =~ s/\t/    /g; # Add your spaces here!
    push(@new, $line);
}

close(FH);

open(FH, '>new.txt');
printf(FH $_) foreach (@new);
close(FH);
```