# How can I replace a single space in every entry of an aray with a tab using Perl? Can I use sed-like commands?

Tags: arrays, perl, sed, indexing

I have an array with several values in the format "xxxxx yyyyyy" at each index.  I want to traverse the array and replace the single place with a tab.  I know I could parse an output file with sed using the substitute command `s/ /\t/`.  Can I do something similar in perl while using a for loop to iterate through the array and re-write each index?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
#print $arg . "\n";
push (@md5, `md5sum $arg`);
}

foreach $entry (@md5) {
$entry = s/ /\t/;
print $entry . "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at ./mymd5.pl line 9.

Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at ./mymd5.pl line 9.

Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at ./mymd5.pl line 9.

Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at ./mymd5.pl line 9.

Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at ./mymd5.pl line 9.

Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at ./mymd5.pl line 9.

Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at ./mymd5.pl line 9.

Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at ./mymd5.pl line 9.
```

Comment: my perl is rusty but I think you want `=~` instead of `=` and a `g` at the end. look for some simple perl regex examples.

Comment: perfect thanks! you should answer so i can give you points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your replacement statement is missing the `g` at the end which makes it global (all occurrences) and the tilde which substitutes in place...

```
$entry =~ s/ /\t/g;
```

The [inverse question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997404/perl-program-to-replace-tabs-with-spaces) is out there...

Comment: (BTW, if you are just starting out with scripting, I'd recommend trying Python instead. Perl is full of underscores and tildes and dollar signs that are better left unlearned.)

Comment: will you see my newest post and help?